# Creating OrderBy parameter dynamically

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, ienumerable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

Hi,
I have a `IEnumerable` of a data class. I want to sort this collection based on user selection. How can i write a generic function which will take the field name to be sorted & will return something line `IEnumerable.OrderBy(f => f.fieldName)`?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here: [Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily. let assume we have an object (class) called `Item` as:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

and this an example of a data collection

```
var items = new List<Item>
                {
                    new Item {Name = "Test 1", Description = "Description 1"},
                    new Item {Name = "Test 2", Description = "Description 2"}
                };
```

using the `switch` condition like

```
IOrderedEnumerable<Item> orderedItems;
switch (selection)
{
    case 1:
        orderedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.Name);
        break;
    case 2:
        orderedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.Description);
        break;
    default:
        orderedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i.Name2);
        break;
}
```

Comment: This solution is demonstrably not what the OP requested.

Comment: oops you are right, i didn't that u need a method to sort by passing the parameter as string so dynamic linq is the solution like the guys mentioned.